# #defines for host OS and cross-compiler conditional code

Tags: c, linux, windows, gcc, mingw

I have a src file that has some code like:

```
#ifndef WIN32
#define ...
#endif
#ifdef WIN32
#define ...
#endif
```

to distinguish what to do when compiling under linux or windows. this worked great when i was building natively under both linux (gcc) and windows (mingw), the windows build being done on a vbox VM on the linux host

now i have pushed on to investigate cross-compilation, and have noticed that cross compiling on a linux host for win32 and win64 with the relevant mingw linux->windows cross-compile tool-chains that WIN32 is defined in this instance

My question is whether there is another `#ifdef` i can use that is defined only for the case when I am using either the mingw win32 or win64 cross-compiler on a linux host, e.g. a `#define` that would not be there if i tried to build natively on windows host from inside my VM?

the reason i need something along these lines is to iron out problems with discrepancies as to how sockets and time.h related stuff is handled under linux/gcc, linux cross compiling to win32 and win64 using mingw and native windows compilation using mingw (its a right nightmare as its a bit different in each case)

Comment: That would seem unlikely. You may need to define your own conditionals when compiling.

Comment: is it that unlikely? i would imagine there would be some useful #defines tucked away in each of the separate build chains that would serve the purpose of distinguishing between them - just have no idea of how to find out what they are.. i'm very new to cross-compiling so maybe i am clutching at straws..

Comment: what i mean is that each build chain will have its own set of system header files and it is there that the useful #define may reside?

Comment: Well, I already gave you my opinion

Comment: For Gcc, `gcc -E -dM` gives you all the macros defined; maybe that helps...

Comment: i'm delving into /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/ but theres a lot of files in there! mafso that is very useful to know will give it a try

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes I think you're right - maybe the approach is to pass in a #define with the -D compiler flag option from my makefile, that way I can make it target specific